# How can I interpret serial data in Arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I've been trying to send and receive serial data to represent a couple sine waves, one before filtering and one after that. I seem to be receiving floats to my result array after sending my data to filter in my Arduino Board, however, I know they don't make sense, since sine data must stay between -1 and 1 and I keep getting values beyond that.

Here's my Python code, from what I was able to gather, I'm sending a string from an array to Arduino in bytes, so I'm guessing I messed up the unpacking and that's why the operations make no sense.

```
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Comunicación Serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3',115200,timeout = 2);
time.sleep = 1;
t = 0; #Señal Ruidosa
d_señal = []; #Graficar
d_filtro = [];
while (t <= 10):
    señal = np.sin(2*np.pi*5*t) + 0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t);
    t = t + 1;
    d_señal.append(str(señal)); #**

for i in d_señal:
    arduino.write(i.encode()); 
    salida = arduino.readline().decode('ascii'); 
    d_filtro.append(salida);

d_filtro[0] = "0.00\r\n" 
cuenta = 0

for k in d_filtro:
    strorg = d_filtro[cuenta];
    strnew = strorg.replace('\r\n','');
    d_filtro[cuenta] = strnew;
    cuenta = cuenta + 1;
   
print(d_filtro);
arduino.close();
```

Here's the Arduino side.

```
String IncomingByte; //Serial Data
float x[] = {0,0,0};  
float y[] = {0,0,0};
float valor = 0.0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    IncomingByte = Serial.read();
    valor = IncomingByte.toFloat();
    x[0] = valor;
    y[0] = 1.91122623*y[1] + -0.91500257*y[2] + 0.00094408*x[0] + 0.00188817*x[1] + 0.00094408*x[2];
    Serial.println(y[0]);
    delay(1); //10ms
    
    for(int i = 1; i >= 0; i--){
      x[i+1] = x[i]; 
      y[i+1] = y[i];
      
    }
    
  }
```

After the whole process, I get data like this:

```
['0.00', '0.04', '0.22', '0.57', '1.08', '1.73', '2.50', '3.41', '4.43', '5.55', '6.77']
```

What am I missing to transfer the data properly?
P.S. Thank you for reading this

Comment: `IncomingByte = Serial.read();` This only reads one byte but the strings you are sending are longer than one byte. Ex "1.2345" is 6 bytes (ascii).

Comment: If the values for the original sine are really small is it worth it to read all the bytes?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the original values are. When you convert the floating point numbers to strings at `d_señal.append(str(señal))` you now have a string value no different than "Hello" or "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" for example. You need to read all the chars on the Arduino side.

Comment: PS: Python does not require `;` at the end of lines.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice!!! I'll look into it

Comment: The simplest solution is to append a newline on the Python side: `arduino.write((i + '\n').encode())`. And on the Arduino side: `Serial.readStringUntil('\n');`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if string encoded floats are transmitted Serial.parseFloat(); is probably easier. and why would you encode a number string to UTF-8?

Comment: @Piglet [`pySerial.write()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write) requires a byte array.

Comment: After trying that, I get this now. ['0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00', '-0.00']

Comment: Start small. Don't try to receive many numbers. Make a code that reliably can send and receive a Float. Then expand this code to receive multiple of them. This way you will see the problems much easier. Try printing what is actually being sent and what is being received. This will help you debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
IncomingByte = Serial.read();
valor = IncomingByte.toFloat();
x[0] = valor;
```

with

```
x[0] = Serial.parseFloat();
```

Make sure you send a delimiter after the number. Otherwise Arduino will wait to receive more digits.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamparsefloat/

Comment: Do I have to change the type of data sent too, or will parse interpret the string received automatically?

Comment: if you send a stiring with numbers it will parse. just test it.

Comment: now I get this on my result array.   `['0.00', '-0.00', '-0.02', '-0.06', '-0.13', '-0.22', '-0.33', '-0.46', '-0.60', '-0.75', '-0.92', '-1.09', '-1.28', '-1.46', '-1.66', '-1.85']`

Comment: well then you probably have another problem in your calculations.

Comment: If I increase the amount of data appended to the array the original problem seems to persist. I don't know how to approach it anymore.

Comment: first you make sure the numbers you send actually arrive at the Arduino using Serial.println(x[0]);  if this is working ok and the numbers are what you expect, forget about the Python part and start to check your Arduino calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to send something that looks like a sine wave then your problem is here:

```
señal = np.sin(2*np.pi*5*t) + 0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t);
```

You see, you are using 11 values created by adding two sine values:

```
d_señal[0]=     sin(0)      + 0.2 x sin(0)
d_señal[1]=     sin(10PI)   + 0.2 x sin(100PI)
d_señal[2]=     sin(20PI)   + 0.2 x sin(200PI)
etc.
```

These terms and sums are all zero, so it seems you need to adjust your "sampling frequency".  I am unaware of how NumPy's trigonometric functions work for LARGE angles, but if it handles them properly these sines should all be zero. Maybe you intended to use `sin(2xPI x t/5) + 0.2 x sin(2xPI x t/50)`?  Also, you haven't shown what values you are sending, and what comes out on the receiving end (ie., `arduino.write()` and `valor`)

Comment: I finally figured it out, it was indeed the sampling and I couldn't see the values because Arduino would round out amounts that were basically 0. After adjusting and using @JohnnyMopp lines it finally worked. Thank you for all of your help!! :)